# Does facebook provide offcial way to register an enterprise facebook developer account?

Tags: facebook

As facebook require real name  registeration, i can't use company name to register.

and facebook require me to upload my id photo, but my account is for public use in our

company, what can i do now?

I know they provice facebook business, but that's not what i need, we are developers,

we just need a public facebook account so that all developers in our team could use.

This is kinda insane to force people use their real name. Google has given up ,why facebook

still persist doing this!

Comment: what can you do now? Make some coffee? Go to beork? here's quite a few possibilities

Comment: Even better, to use the developer resources, you need to verify your account with a mobile number...

Comment: as private , i might have my personal facebook account, if facebook force us to use id photo that means my id used to register multiple account? one for personal use , one or more for company use?!??